# Google Cloud Function is working even after deleting the container image from the container registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

**My Question:** Having the below understanding, if I delete the container image from the container registry, the function should not work when triggered.But it works. Why this happens?

Following are the understanding

**When a function is deployed**

1. The source code is zipped and saved in storage bucket.
2. The source code is pulled and built into container image.
3. This container image is stored in Cloud Registry.

**When a function is triggered**

1. The image is pulled form the container registry.
2. A new container is spun and response is sent back.

**Note:** This is not because of container caching. Because this happens even if the function is triggered after 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

The image in the Container Registry is only used during the build, and is actually not used by Cloud Functions afterwards. In fact, the Firebase CLI removes the image after the deploy completes, so there's no way for GCF to find it.

Our engineers are checking with the GCF team about why the documentation says something different, but given your testing and how our tooling behaves, it seems to be a documentation mistake.

Comment: Fwiw this page https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building says `Cloud Functions accesses this image when it needs to run the container to execute your function.` I assume this is what resulted in this question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but a little more explanation would help me a lot.

Let's take this example

Say I deployed a cloud function.
At this point a container image is created and stored in cloud registry.
There won't be any container running because I haven't triggered it yet.(Correct me if I am wrong)
Now I delete the image from cloud registry.
If I trigger the function, according to the documentation, it will search for the container image to run the container.
Since I deleted the image earlier the function should fail.

Why is this not happening?

Comment: @somethingsomething The Firebase CLI deletes these images after the deployment has succeeded. I'm not sure why the GCF docs contains that line, so our team is checking with them.